# How to program SQL views to show on website?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

So I have several report views that are relevant for a few people that have no SQL knowledge

Without using tableau, how to have these views available to be visualized on an internal website and/or downloadable in the form of a csv file?

Database is postgresql and there's someone else with JavaScript knowledge, though any solution is fine as long as it can be simple for the end user

Comment: The answer to your question is: "Yes, yes there is a way to display data on a website."  To elaborate further, you can select any of a number of languages/frameworks/technologies and get started with some introductory tutorials.  The client-side (in-browser) language is always JavaScript.  If you also want to use JavaScript for your server-side language, take a look at Node.js.

Comment: @david the question is how

Comment: The answer is still the same.  You'd pick your web application development technologies of choice and start with some tutorials on them.  Just about any web development language will have introductory tutorials/examples readily available on the internet which show how to connect to a database and display data.  As you progress in your application development, we can help with specific questions about specific code.  But Stack Overflow does not seek to provide complete customized tutorials.  To learn more about this community you are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @david I'm simply asking for help on something I don't know but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to export data of a table to a CSV file is with the COPY statement. But you can only COPY directly from a table, not a view.  But you can 
copy out anything you can select, so this should work:

`COPY (SELECT * FROM MyView) TO 'C:\tmp\MyData_db.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this. But still I need to make this available for people on the internal website instead of having them run commands on the command line as they are even worse than me when it comes to coding